# Adding application/json header in get returns error 500?

Tags: php, flutter, codeigniter-4

I have an API server developed in codeigniter 4 and flutter app that connects to it. I'm having a problem when I tried to use http.get. when I added application/json in the header it returs error 500. But if I change it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` it works. Also when I deleted the whole headers parameter it works too. Is this the default behavior?

Here the sample client code in flutter:

```
  dynamic get(String path, {Map<dynamic, dynamic> params}) async {
    print(getPath(path, params));
    final response = await _client.get(
      getPath(path, params),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    );
```

Here is my Controller in CI4:

```
public function getTest()
{
    $testParam = $this->request->getVar('testParam');

    $result = $this->model->where('test =' . $testParam . ' AND (IsDeleted IS NULL OR IsDeleted=0)')
        ->first();

    if ($result != null) {
        $response['result']  = $result;
        $response['msg'] = "Success";

        return $this->respond($response);
    } else {
        return $this->failNotFound('record not found.');
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Here's the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError Object
(
[message:protected] => Argument 2 passed to dot_array_search() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\api.test\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\HTTP\IncomingRequest.php on line 360
```

It seems that the parameter becomes null when `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` is in the header.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: @aynber I tried adding `try catch` on the whole getTest function but it never returns error. Also tried adding `print_r('test')` at the first line of the function and it doesn't even called. But its all working when I removed `Content-Type': 'application/json` from the flutter request.

Comment: @aynber Sorry I edited wrong script. Will update the question with the error.